# the loss of CNN in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

When I train the CNN network, the loss will become very large at the beginning, and then slowly decrease. Why does it suddenly become bigger? Is it a problem with the loss function or activation function, or something else?

[image]

Comment: This is normal behavior. You start with randomly initialized model’s parameters which result in high loss value and then move (at learning rate) towards low loss value regions of parameter space. 1. Read about gradient descent and back propagation. 2. This is not a place for questions about ML/DNN theory.

Comment: Thanks you very much.And I have another question to ask.If I want to use maxout as activation function , how should I write the codes in Tensorflow? An input parameter is required in the slim.maxout() function, so it cannot be used for slim.arg_scope([slim.conv],activation_fn=slim.maxout)?What should I do?